Scene turned all gray in Godot after focusing an object
VERSION : Godot 4.3 mono
Hi everyone,
I've recently started transitioning from Unity (that I've been using for 10 years) to Godot, and I'm going NUTS on super basic stuff (please don't make fun of me :( ).
Ok so here's the problem : I wanted to focus on an object in the scene view. In Unity, I would just double click the object in the hierarchy. In Godot, I saw on a forum that clicking the object then pressing F with the cursor on the scene view had the same effect. However, when I did this, this happened :

My scene view turned gray (I suppose because the scene view went super far from my objects ?) and I have NO IDEA how to undo that (even restarting the editor didn't work).
I know the answer is probably super stupid, but I'm helpless here.
Please help me :'(
EDIT :
When I try to add an object where the scene view is, it says I'm trying to instantiate at (nan, nan) px.


This seems to be a bug. What happens if you select the root node for example and press f in the view? You could also try to rename the .godot folder in your project and reopen the editor again.

wow renaming the folder worked, you're a genius ! Can I have an explanation ?

Ok so I can reproduce the bug by clicking "center view" anytime. Maybe I should install an older version.

Godot caches files and settings into this folder. Since it also happened on restarting godot, this was the only clue I got. Sadly I can not say for certain which file exactly could cause this effect
